# Using Winston in typescript

Tags: typescript, winston

I can't figure how to use the logging module Winston in typescript. I have an error when I try to set the logger level, and another one when I try to log an error:

```
import * as logger from "winston";

logger.level = 'debug';
// [ts] Cannot assign to 'level' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

logger.error(new Error('test'));
// [ts] Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I have added both `winston` and `@types/winston` to my project.

---

**Edit:** to complete Joshua answer, it seem that by default winston logs to... nowhere. You have to add a transport to make it work:

```
import * as logger from "winston";

logger.configure({
    level: 'debug',
    transports: [
        new logger.transports.Console({
            colorize: true
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the type definitions for Winston:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/winston/index.d.ts

If you look at the bottom of the file, the default export is declared as `const`, so when you try to modify the `level` property, it complains at you because you are trying to modify a `const` object. Here are the relevant lines:

```
declare const winston: winston.Winston;
export = winston;
```

Instead of trying to set that property directly, try using the `configure` method (note that your `logger` import is of type `Winston`:

```
logger.configure({
    level: 'verbose',
    ...
})
```

If this doesn't work (I'm not sure exactly what else the configure call expects), you might try creating a new `LoggerInstance`, which you will be able to modify.

Your second error is because you're passing an `Error` object where a `string` is expected. The declaration of Winston.info is here:

```
info: LeveledLogMethod;
```

And here is the LeveledLogMethod interface:

```
interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (msg: string, callback: LogCallback): LoggerInstance;
    (msg: string, meta: any, callback: LogCallback): LoggerInstance;
    (msg: string, ...meta: any[]): LoggerInstance;
}
```

Comment: does this mean it is impossible to log error with Winston ? that sound insane to me.

Comment: You could log the `Error`'s `message` property.

Comment: this actually log the error:
let err:any = new Error('test');
logger.error(err);
I thing there is a problem with the type definition for winston.

Comment: Another way that should work would be to use the third form defined in the interface, which is to do something like `logger.error("test", new Error("test error");` I think you are correct that the type definition is incorrect. I think it should also include `(...meta: any[]): LoggerInstance;`, but I'm not sure about the syntax exactly. After looking through the source, it appears to me that the `log` method tries to smartly handle objects it receives such as `Error`s, and the `meta` parameter is an indication of that.

Comment: I have opened an issue : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18220